# Firestore Security Rule: Allow read only for Author rule not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to secure my Documents with a `availability` status, that can be `public` or `private`. Everybody can read `public` Documents and `private` Documents can be read by Users who have created the Document (meaning `creatorUid` is set to the user's uid).

These are my rules:

```
match /Routines/{document} {      
    allow read: if resource.data.availability == "public" ||  (resource.data.availability == "private" && resource.data.creatorUid == request.auth.uid);
    allow write: if true;
}
```

I have created some tests to see if my rules work:

```
describe.only("Routine Routine Rules", () => {

    const userAuthA = { uid: "user123", email: "userA@test.com" };

    const demoRoutinePrivate = {
        id: "DemoRoutine",
        title: "Demo Routine",
        availability: "private",
        creatorUid: userAuthA.uid,
        exercises: []
    }

    it("Authors can read private routines", async () => {
        const admin = getAdminFirestore();
        await admin.collection("Routines").doc(demoRoutinePrivate.id).set(demoRoutinePrivate);

        const db1 = getAuthedFirestore(userAuthA);
        const routines1 = db1.collection("Routines").where("creatorUid", "==", userAuthA.uid);
        const routine1 = db1.collection("Routines").doc(demoRoutinePrivate.id);
        await firebase.assertSucceeds(routines1.get());
        await firebase.assertSucceeds(routine1.get());
    });
});
```

However, I get this error:

```
FirebaseError: 
Property availability is undefined on object. for 'list' @ L33
```

I'm pretty certain that my Document has the `availabilty` property set, so I don't understand the error.

EDIT: here is the screenshot of the document: [image]

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of that document?

Comment: @Dharmaraj added a screenshot

Comment: @Dharmaraj nvm, figured it out, see my comment below

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had an error in my query.

```
const routines1 = db1.collection("Routines").where("creatorUid", "==", userAuthA.uid);
```

the correct query is:

```
const routines1 = db1.collection("Routines").where("availability", "==", "private").where("creatorUid", "==", userAuthA.uid);
```

although the original error message is not very helpful...